# Memcached bucket throws exception

Tags: node.js, npm, couchbase

I have a process which connects to a couchbase server and accesses 2 buckets (one is a couchbase bucket and other is a memcached bucket).

Randomly (1 in 10 times) when I restart the process I get an error

`"Error: cannot perform operations on a shutdown bucket"`

Weird part is this error is only occurring when trying to access the memcached bucket and not the couchbase bucket.

Also on restarting the process again everything works fine and able to access both the buckets

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Due to couchbase implementation with callback, you need perform operations in the callback function of `cluster.openBucket`. Ensure you have not operations out this callback.

Comment: that might help. will try it out. Thanks